# How to make innodb as default engine

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to make Innodb as my default engine and I changed this in the my.cnf file.

I set default-storage-engine=InnoDB in my.cnf file and restarted mysql but still it's not taking it.

Even after restarting the server, it's still showing default engine as MyISAM.

> show engines

+------------+---------+-
| Engine     | Support |
+------------+---------+-
| InnoDB     | YES     |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     |
| CSV        | YES     |
| MEMORY     | YES     |
| FEDERATED  | NO      |
| ARCHIVE    | YES     |
| **MyISAM     | DEFAULT** |
+------------+---------+-

How can I change it to InnoDB ?

Comment: Can you please try default-storage-engine=innobase?

Comment: default-storage-engine=innobase - Nope it did not work..

Comment: @user476554 - check your full command that you used to connect to mysql, Or `show variables like '%engine%';`

Comment: mysql> show variables like "%engine%"
    -> ;
+---------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name             | Value  |
+---------------------------+--------+
| engine_condition_pushdown | ON     |
| storage_engine            | MyISAM |
+---------------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure you add this line in the proper section of the my.cnf file. It needs to be in the `[mysqld]`section:

```
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

Also, comment out any other line in my.cnf that may be setting it to MyISAM.

Comment: This is my my.cnf file 

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
user=mysql
table_cache = 2048
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_log_file_size=128M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=4M
innodb_table_locks = 0
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
join_buffer_size=2M
query_cache_size=512M
sort_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=8M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
key_buffer = 512M
key_buffer_size=256M
max_allowed_packet=16M
max_connections=250
long_query_time=5
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Comment: Thank u...I for got to put [mysqld] to start mysqld section in my.cnf file...then I restarted and it worked

Comment: Also modify the [wampmysqld64] section