# How to force innodb database type creation in Spring-Boot 2?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using `spring-boot-2.0.3` with `hibernate` and would like to use database table auto generation.

Problem: by default `myisam` tables are created, but I'd prefer `innodb`. Adding the following properties work to change the tables always to innodb, but which of those properties should be the preferred way?

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

Is there any drawback using one over the other?

Sidenote: this is NOT a duplicate (the linked question is in no way about java/hibernate/spring)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make innodb as default engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199446/how-to-make-innodb-as-default-engine)

Comment: You need both so there isn't a preferred way as both are necessary. Although I believe that as of MySQL 5.5 the default storage switched to InnoDB. Which will be switched if you use an older MySQL dialect from hibernate.

Comment: Using `MySQL57Dialect` has other advantages than just specifying the storage engine...